# Video getting stuck(freeze) while swipe ViewPager too fast

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I m getting issue with Video getting freeze while swiping view pager fast.

**Problem:**

I have one *webm* extension type video (12 seconds) and playing it in VideoView.

From that video i m getting current position from that video and pause that video at the interval of 4 seconds. For that i m using handler and it works fine when i swipe slowly but when i swipe fast the video is getting stuck (freeze) and not working properly.

**Code:**

```
 ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        currentPosition = position;


        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            videoPlayPause(0);
        }

        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
            videoPlayPause(5);
        }

        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
            videoPlayPause(9);
        }
    }
};


void playVideo() {
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.welcome;
    autoFitVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    autoFitVideoView.requestFocus();
    autoFitVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    autoFitVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {

            autoFitVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    });
}

 public void videoPlayPause(final int seekto) {


    autoFitVideoView.seekTo(seekto * 1000);

    autoFitVideoView.start();

    autoFitVideoView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            videoCurrentPosition = autoFitVideoView.getCurrentPosition();

            if (currentPosition == 0) {
                if (videoCurrentPosition == 0) {
                    pauseVideo(3000);
                }
            }

            if (currentPosition == 1) {
                if (videoCurrentPosition == 5000) {
                    pauseVideo(3000);
                }
            }

            if (currentPosition == 2) {
                if (videoCurrentPosition == 9000) {
                    pauseVideo(4000);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

void pauseVideo(long delayTime) {

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            autoFitVideoView.pause();
        }
    }, delayTime);

}
```

Also ViewPager contains only the text array and with swipe text i m showing video with time interval of 4 seconds. But video getting freezes.

**XML:**

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_desc"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title">

    <in.hammerapps.view.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"></in.hammerapps.view.CustomViewPager>


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</FrameLayout>
```

So, Any advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try enabling hardware acceleartion in the manifest file

Comment: No.It does not work

Comment: @Mani Finally I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by using `CountDownTimer` instead of `Handler`.

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // This is globally declared


void pauseVideo(final long delayTime) {

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(delayTime, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            if (autoFitVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                autoFitVideoView.pause();
            }
        }

    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

In `onPageSelected` method of `ViewPager` you need to cancel the previous `countDownTimer`. That's the most import thing you need to otherwise it will not work.

```
 @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        currentPosition = position;

        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();    // Most important thing
        }


        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {

            videoPlayPause(0);

        }

        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {

            videoPlayPause(5);
        }

        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {

            videoPlayPause(9);

        }
    }
```